# What is the purpose of this mysterious _TppWaiterpThread thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, windows-7, windows-7-x64

Consider this code sample for LookupPrivilegeValue taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with minor code formatting edits)

```
BOOL SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege) {
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
LUID luid;

if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid ) )  {
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
    return FALSE; 
}
// SET A BREAKPOINT BELOW, notice a new thread was created
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
if (bEnablePrivilege) {
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
}
else {
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
}
// Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.
if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges( hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 
(PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD) NULL) ) { 
      printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
      return FALSE; 
} 

if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED) {
      printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
      return FALSE;
} 
return TRUE;
}
```

Using VS 2010/2008 debugger after the first call to LookupPrivilegeValue I've noticed that a new worker thread called _TppWaiterpThread@4 was created. This thread lives until the process exits and its stack trace is the following:

```
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()  
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0xc bytes   
ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4()  + 0x12c bytes  
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Tested on Windows 7 x86/x64 (remote/local debugging). I tried setting two privileges SE_DEBUG_NAME & SE_SYSTEM_NAME. This is how I've called SetPrivilege:

```
HANDLE hProcess;
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, GetCurrentProcessId());
SetPrivilege(hProcess, SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME, TRUE);
//SetPrivilege(hProcess, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
```

On XP this new thread does not appear.

So my questions are:

- What is the purpose of this _TppWaiterpThread thread?
- Is LookupPrivilegeValue creating this thread behind the scenes to complete its work?

Comment: I think the translation is done via a RPC call to smss.exe, the thread is there to service RPC.

Comment: @avakar: Thanks! I've continued the analysis today and the stack trace from LookupPrivilegeValue seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the internal implementation of a worker factory. Typically, one thread per factory is used to wait for all waitable events. When an event occurs, the waiter thread dispatches a job to one of the worker threads to handle the event.

This is all part of the [tpWorkerFactory](http://mba.shengwushibie.com/itbook/BookChapter.asp?id=28287) implementation.